# Override snippet in Sublime Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, code-snippets

In Sublime Text 2, I'd like to create a snippet for Rails `image_tag`.

I want `it` to be a trigger, but it seems that it is already taken by `<input>`.
I'd like to remove `<input>` snippet at all. I've looked through most of Sublime packages, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Is there an easy way to find or override the `<input>` snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are dead set on using `it` to trigger the snippet, you will need to edit this file:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/HTML.tmLanguage
```

and remove `input` from the string

```
<key>begin</key>
        <string>(&lt;/?)((?i:a|abbr|acronym|area|b|base|basefont|bdo|big|br|button|caption|cite|code|col|colgroup|del|dfn|em|font|head|html|i|img|input|ins|isindex|kbd|label|legend|li|link|map|meta|noscript|optgroup|option|param|q|s|samp|script|select|small|span|strike|strong|style|sub|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|title|tr|tt|u|var)\b)</string>
```

Next, comment out this line

```
{ "trigger": "input", "contents": "<input>" },
```

from `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-completions`

`input` should now be free to use as you like in HTML scopes.

Comment: Used this solution for a PHP snippet and all I had to do was edit the .sublime-completions file. Thank you @AGS. By the way, editing the .tmLanguage file broke PHP syntax recognition for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools` -> `New Snippet...` and the write the following:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<%= image_tag ${1}, ${2} %>   
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>it</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

And finally save the snippet.

This snippet it's working perfectly for me.